# Formas mais elegantes de fazer inversão de integers, arrays e strings em Python

Tags: python, array, string, inteiros

Salve!

Tenho procurado formas elegantes de fazer a inversao de strings, arrays e integers em Python.

O que acham desses meus códigos abaixo e o que sugerem para melhorá-los? Eles funcionam...

Obrigado!

```
frase = 'eu gosto de python'[::-1]
numero = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
inteiro = 123456
numeroInvertido = int(str(inteiro)[::-1])
print frase
print numero [::-1]
print numeroInvertido
```

Comment: Olá, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! As soluções me parece razoáveis - embora eu não seja um perito em Python. Mas talvez fosse bem explicar o que exatamente você pretende fazer com os valores invertidos. Por exemplo, se a ideia for apenas iterar uma vez sobre uma lista invertida talvez não seja muito eficiente duplicar a lista em memória.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sobre esta forma:

```
frase = 'eu gosto de python'[::-1]
```

Não apenas é a forma mais performática como também a mais rápida para todos os casos. Isto também vale para esta forma:

```
numero = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17][::-1]
```

E, portanto, esta:

```
numeroInvertido = int(str(inteiro)[::-1])
```

Para o caso de *strings*, há ainda está forma:

```
''.join(reversed('eu gosto de python'))
```

Mas esta forma é mais lenta.

Para listas, você ainda pode fazer:

```
list(reversed([12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]))
```

Também mais lenta. Ou ainda:

```
numero = [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
print(numero.reverse())
```

Em resumo, sim, você utiliza as melhores formas de inverter as estruturas de dados mencionadas.

Comment: E para inverter os dígitos de um inteiro? Tratar como string também é a melhor solução?

Comment: Sem usar matemática, é a melhor solução. Posso colocar essa observação na resposta.