# Iterando um string dentro do for

Tags: python, string, for

Como o for consegue pegar a string de trás pra frente utilizando len com -1 -1 -1?

```
nome = 'felipe'
for c in range(len(nome)-1, -1, -1):
    print(nome[c], c)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! Você colocou uma imagem do código e/ou mensagem de erro. Apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é! Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar o código e alterar algo dentro. Clique no link [edit] e **coloque o código/erro como texto**. Veja mais sobre isso nesses links - [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/3774), [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta ver a [documentação de `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range). Mas basicamente, um `range` possui 3 valores:

- valor inicial
- valor final
- passo

Sendo que o valor inicial é incluso e o final não (por exemplo, para um `range` com valor inicial 1, valor final 5 e passo 1, os valores que ele inclui seriam 1, 2, 3 e 4).

E para criar um `range`, você pode passar 1, 2 ou 3 parâmetros. Ex:

- `range(7)`: com apenas um parâmetro, este passa a ser o valor final. O valor inicial é setado para zero e o passo será 1. Portanto, este `range` abrange os valores 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 e 6.
- `range(2, 7)`: com dois parâmetros, estes passam a ser o valor inicial e final. O passo é setado para 1. Portanto, este `range` abrange os valores 2, 3, 4, 5 e 6.
- `range(1, 7, 2)`: com três parâmetros, estes passam a ser o valor inicial, final e o passo. Portanto, este `range` abrange os valores 1, 3 e 5 (o passo define que os valores pulam de 2 em 2, e lembre-se que o valor final - o 7 - não é incluso).

---

Só que um `range` também pode estar em ordem decrescente, mas para isso o passo precisa ser negativo. Por exemplo, `range(5, -1, -1)` possui o valor inicial 5, valor final -1 e passo -1, por isso ele inclui os valores 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 e 0, nesta ordem.

No caso do seu código, o valor inicial é `len(nome) - 1`, ou seja, o tamanho da string `nome` (`len(nome)`) subtraído de 1 (portanto, `5`). Ou seja, primeiro será pego o caractere da posição 5 (que é o último, já que a primeira posição é zero), depois da posição 4, e assim por diante.

---

Apenas para constar, também seria possível fazer o mesmo usando [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) (para obter os elementos e seus respectivos índices) juntamente com [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) para inverter a ordem:

```
nome = 'felipe'
for indice, caractere in reversed(list(enumerate(nome))):
    print(caractere, indice)
```

Por fim, não deixe de ver também [outras formas de inverter uma string](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/95003/112052).

Comment: Então quer dizer que o len(nome) - 1 sera o 5 ? e vai até o 0 porque o -1 não é incluido,  daí ele vai voltar uma casa com -1 ? eu também notei que o len(nome) conta como 6 então é por isso que coloca o -1 pra ficar 5 que na verdade esse 5 vai de 0 a 4?

Comment: @FelipeSoares `nome` é uma string com 6 caracteres, então `len(nome)` é 6, e portanto `len(nome) - 1` é 5. Então o range criado é `range(5, -1, -1)`, ou seja, vai de 5 até -1 (sendo que o -1 não é incluso, por isso ele para no zero), e o passo é -1, ou seja, ele percorre os valores 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 e 0, nesta ordem

Comment: Cara! eu acho que entendi, muito obrigado! você me ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 2):

A função "len()" é um builtin do python ele retorna o tamanho  da string ( direto ao assunto vem internamente na linguagem)

```
>>> len("felipe")
6
```

Para manipular strings pode usar o slice usado para fatiar strings, listas, tuplas..

```
string = "python"
```

## string[start,stop,step]

```
#start : inicia em uma dada posição
#stop : para em uma posição
#step : pule

###############
```

string[1:4]

p | y | t | h | o | n
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5

```
string[1:4]
'yth'

#iniciei no indice 1 até a posição 4
#então cortei a string de acordo com a posição

string[0:6:1] 
'python'

string[0:6:2] #iniciei na posição 0 até 6 e foi indicado que pule 2 em 2 posição
'pto'


para inverter basta seguir o inverso da posição:
string[::1]# nao foi adicionado o inicio nem onde deve parar mas o pula foi indicado 1 em 1
'python'
string[::-1]# negativo inverta
'nohtyp'



for indice in nome[::-1]:
  print(indice)
 
e
p
i
l
e
f

for indice in nome[::1]: 
  print(indice)
f
e
l
i
p
e
```

Comment: Obrigado irmão!